# Manage multiple concurrent inserts in sql server db using c#

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

How can we manage 1000s of concurrent insert at a time in sql server using c#...

Regards
V.

Comment: bcp, BULK INSERT... bulk load syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to think what kind of [transaction isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) will provide the right mix of performance and correctness. Also, each concurrent transaction will need to be inside its own [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) ([BeginTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx) will throw an exception if you try to call it without first ending the previous transaction).

I can't say more until you explain what you mean by "manage"?